# How does Lead By Example work when the squad leader has a lower will value than the rest of the squad?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

If the squad leader has a lower will value than other members in the squad, but **Lead By Example** is purchased, will the higher willed units use the lower value?

In that situation, if the squad leader panics due to a broken window, will the higher willed, but lower ranking squad members also panic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No.

The text of the Lead by Example skill states that

> The squad leader substitutes his or her Will for that of all nearby
>   lower-Will squadmates.

This does not suggest that the squad leader has any effect on squadmates with higher will than the leader, and it does not suggest any effect at all relating to panics.

Comment: im only relating to panics as a example, not as a whole.

Comment: @ken bad example, because so far as I know panic is not deterministic - AIUI the Will level only affects the *chance* to panic. So just because somebody with Will 100 panics, that does not mean that every soldier with Will < 100 will automatically panic. In any case, the answer to both the question in the title and the example in the body of your question is "no" :-)

Comment: fair enough. well then i've now got the answer.